# Dynamic Tabs creation using jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

How to create dynamic tabs inside the jetpack compose, in my application the number of tabs i need to show depends upon API response. But when i am setting the TabsRow, we need to set the **selectedTabIndex** value, and this is causing the issue. Because before the tabs data get loaded, it's trying to build the ui without any tab inside.

Please help me to fix this or please guide me to do it in right ways.

```
@Composable
fun CustomTab(viewModel: BeatsViewModel) {
    var tabIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val beats = viewModel.beatsData.observeAsState().value
    ScrollableTabRow(selectedTabIndex = tabIndex) {
        beats?.forEachIndexed { index, beatData ->
            val selected = tabIndex == index
            Tab(selected = selected, onClick = {
                tabIndex = index
            }) {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(10.dp)
                        .height(50.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
                ) {
                    Box(
                        Modifier
                            .size(24.dp)
                            .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                            .background(color = if (selected) Color.Red else Color.White)
                    )
                    Text(
                        text = beatData.mBeatName,
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
                        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is throwing the error as below (even before my viewmodel post any value to beatsData) -

```
Process: in.bizom.android, PID: 23133
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at androidx.compose.material.TabRowKt$ScrollableTabRow$1.invoke(TabRow.kt:230)
        at androidx.compose.material.TabRowKt$ScrollableTabRow$1.invoke(TabRow.kt:228)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.material.TabRowKt$ScrollableTabRow$2$1$2$3.invoke(TabRow.kt:299)
        at androidx.compose.material.TabRowKt$ScrollableTabRow$2$1$2$3.invoke(TabRow.kt:298)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$subcompose$2$1$1.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:251)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$subcompose$2$1$1.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:251)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerKt.invokeComposable(Composer.kt:3337)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2582)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2571)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:247)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source:1)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:2571)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:2522)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:478)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:748)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$CompositionContextImpl.composeInitial$runtime_release(Composer.kt:2987)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$CompositionContextImpl.composeInitial$runtime_release(Composer.kt:2987)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:433)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState.subcomposeInto(SubcomposeLayout.kt:269)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState.access$subcomposeInto(SubcomposeLayout.kt:154)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$subcompose$2.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:244)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$subcompose$2.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:241)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.withNoObservations(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:142)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.withNoSnapshotReadObservation$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:55)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.withNoSnapshotReadObservation$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:1175)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:241)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:235)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState.subcompose$ui_release(SubcomposeLayout.kt:224)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$Scope.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:490)
        at androidx.compose.material.TabRowKt$ScrollableTabRow$2$1$2.invoke(TabRow.kt:298)
        at androidx.compose.material.TabRowKt$ScrollableTabRow$2$1$2.invoke(TabRow.kt:273)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:68)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$createMeasurePolicy$1$measure$1.placeChildren(SubcomposeLayout.kt:367)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$layoutChildren$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:993)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$layoutChildren$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:978)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an empty state view for that screen. How would it look like before the data is loaded from the API/ database? You can use a loading indicator, a message, etc. But you need to account for that.

Comment: Hi cd, I am just trying to build the tab layout, with multiple Scrollable Tabs. I don't even have any dependent screen yet. So my question was how to create such tab layout. and if you mean 'empty state view for that screen' is for particular tab item, how would we do that?

Comment: Let me explain in more details with ref image - https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/cdn-cgi/image/width=630/uploads/users/1499/posts/30120/image/cfcf.png
How to build just tab layout like above ref image.